# Array to map based on object property containing array items

Tags: javascript, node.js

If i have a object like following

```
result  = [
 {
   phones : ["ABC", "DEF"],
   name: "Simon"
 },
 {
   phones : ["ABC", "XZY"],
   name: "John"
 }
]
```

Expected output

Map of key, value

```
{ABC,     ["Simon", "John"]}
{DEF,     ["Simon"]}
{XYZ,     ["John"]}
```

My try

```
map: Map = new Map();   
for ( r of result ) {
   for( phone of r.phones) {
      if(map.get(phone)){
        map.put(phone, map.get(phone).concat(r.name))
      } else {
        map.put(phone, r.name);
      }
   }
}
```

Is there a ES6 way to perform the above function ?

Comment: That is ECMAScript 2015 (ES6). What are you expecting?

Comment: @evolutionxbox Thanks for your comment. I was wondering if there was some minimised way of doing the double iteration. :)

Comment: That would be better asked on https://codereview.stackexchange.com/ not here. (Unless the code doesn't do what you want of course)

Comment: @evolutionxbox My apologies. I was not aware of the code review link. Any way i can move automatically to code review or i have to copy paste ?

Comment: I don't know of a way except copy/paste.

Answer (score 0):

Using [Array.prototype.reduce](https://developer.mozilla.org/en/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Array/reduce), you can do this.

```js
const input = [{
  phones: ["ABC", "DEF"],
  name: "Simon"
},
{
  phones: ["ABC", "XZY"],
  name: "John"
}];

const result = input.reduce((acc, cur) => {
  cur.phones.forEach((item) => {
    acc[item] ? acc[item].push(cur.name) : acc[item] = [ cur.name ];
  });
  return acc;
}, {});
console.log(result);
```

Answer (score 0):

I don't know if it's ES6 enough, but using map-reduce gives something like this:

```
result.reduce((map, person) => {
  person.phones.forEach(phone => 
    map.has(phone)
      ? map.get(phone).push(person.name)
      : map.set(phone, [person.name])
  );
  return map;
}, new Map());
```

But the code is more or less the same, the performance are probably not that far off, and readability is in the eye of the reader.

In short, your mileage may vary.